# MySQL group by day with datetime mixing same dates from different months

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to group posts from same day, the problem is that 2/20 gets grouped with 3/20 (20 = 20)

How can this be fixed?

This is my current code:

```
select day(Date), count(*) from Posts WHERE shopID != '' group by shopID, day(Date)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to group by every piece that might be different. So add `MONTH(Date)` and even `YEAR(Date)` depending on the scope of your query.

```
select DAY(Date), count(*) from Posts WHERE shopID != '' group by shopID, YEAR(Date), MONTH(Date), DAY(Date)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also group this way: `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date(date))`, instead of grouping by year, month and day separately

```
select date(date), count(*) from Posts
WHERE shopID != ''
group by shopID, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date(date))
```

Note you'll have to also take the other date data in the select statement to be able to recognize which month/year the day belongs to. If you don't you'll get a lot of day numbers and counts, but the day numbers will be repeated for each month/year.

That's why I used `date(date), count(*)`.