# Pull entries based on a datetime field and organize by month and year

Tags: php, mysql, sql, group-by

I have a table named 'tasks' that contains a bunch of information (who it's assigned to, date it was created, date its due, etc)

The 'task_due_date' field is a normal datetime field. I'd like to organize all of the tasks by this; for example, if you had 3 tasks in March 2013 and 4 in April, I want to separate them into divs for each month so they can be collapsible for easy reading.

I was wondering what the best way to go about this is? How can I make it future-proof? I know I could manually write PHP loops for each year (if month is 1, do this, if month is 2 do this, etc) but it seems there has to be a much more efficient way.

It needs to be aware of years as well, so January 2013 should have its down versus January 2014.

My dream solution would be:

- March 2013: Task 1, Task 2
- April 2013: Task 1
- May 2013: Task 1, Task 2

Here is the SQL for my tasks table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tasks` (
`ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`task_status` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
`task_creation_date` datetime NOT NULL,
`task_due_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
`task_completed_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`task_priority` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
`task_assignment` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
`task_description` longtext NOT NULL,
`task_type` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
KEY `task_type` (`task_type`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=2698 ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there will be a lot of tasks, you might consider generating the 'monthly' divs and retrieving the actual tasks via an AJAX load.

You'll be able to show the number of tasks per year/month by grouping them with a query;

```
SELECT 
   COUNT(*) AS number_of_tasks, 
   YEAR(task_due_date) AS task_year, 
   MONTH(task_due_date) AS task_month 
FROM tasks 
GROUP BY task_year, task_month;
```

With this, create the divs, then retrieve (via AJAX) all tasks within the selected year/month with this query

```
SELECT *
FROM tasks 
   WHERE YEAR(task_due_date) = 2013, 
   AND MONTH(task_due_date) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a `group by` SQL query

See this it might be helpful

[MySQL group by day with datetime mixing same dates from different months](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9849304/mysql-group-by-day-with-datetime-mixing-same-dates-from-different-months)

Answer (score 0):

This will give you your, close to your, "dream solution", although I may have taken that a bit too literal:

```
SELECT
  CONCAT(
    DATE_FORMAT( `task_due_date`, '%M %Y' ),
    ': ',
    GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT( 'Task ', `ID` ) SEPARATOR ', ' )
  ) AS `tasks_per_month`
FROM
  `tasks`
GROUP BY
  DATE_FORMAT( `task_due_date`, '%M %Y' )
ORDER BY
  `task_due_date`;
```